# only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [NoneType]

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

Am getting this on callback, am using Plotly dash, The data frame is of object types, is this an issue with "value =" in dcc.dropdown?. But a similar dropdown works fine!!

```
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                           id="account_name_selector",
                           options=[{"label": i, "value": i} for i in df["Account_Name"].unique()],
                           multi=True,
                           value=[i for i in df["Account_Name"].unique()],
                           className="dcc_control",
                       ),



@app.callback(
   Output("main_graph", "figure"),
   [
       Input("account_name_selector", "value"),
       Input("week_selector", "value"),
   ]
)

def main_graph_fig(account_name_value, week_value):

   dff = df[df.Week.isin(week_value) & df.Account_Name.isin(account_name_value)]
```

Comment: You need to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code AND your data for anyone to be able to try to recreate your problem, along with the complete Traceback.

Comment: That said, given the error suggesting you have passed a `NoneType`, what debugging have you done? Have you tried simply printing the value of `value=[i for i in df["Account_Name"].unique()]` as the message simply suggests that it's `None`